# Solve PDE using finite difference method

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, pde, numerical-computing

Using Matlab, I am trying to solve PDEs by the finite difference method. The coupled PDEs are as follows:
[the coupled PDEs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlVTM.png)

How should I handle this term surrounded by a black frame? I tried many ways, and all failed.

Comment: What did you try? Also, this may be better suited to [scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).